# "Invalid token" or "Audiance Invalid" Azure Ad Authentication

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, jwt

I created a SPA in Angular and a WEB API with .net6. Both should be authenticated with Azure AD. The  client authentication in the SPA works fine and I get the following jwt

```
{
"aud": "MyFrontendAppID",
"iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/a59..../v2.0",
"email": "me@email.com",
"name": "ME",
[...]
"ver": "2.0"
}
```

After calling my api with this bearer token I get "Invalid token" or "Audiance Invalid" depending on my config if I use the audiance or not
In my appsettings.json i had this

```
"AzureAd": {
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
"TenantId": "MYTentantID",
"ClientId": "api://MyBackendAppID",
"Audience": "MyFrontendAppID"
}
```

We have configured 2 applications in Azure one for the API and one for the Frontend. In the Frontend we add the permission for the API Scopes like this
[image]

[image]

**Update 27.05.2022**
Changed appsettings.json for the backend in this way

```
"AzureAd": {
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
"TenantId": "MYTenantID",
//"ClientId": "Tried also with MyBackendAppId",
"ClientId": "MyFrontendAppID",
"Audience": "MyFrontendAppID",
"Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/MyTenantID/v2.0",
"Scopes": "api://MyBackendAppId/AccessAsUser"
}
```

But it don't work also.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with any of  below ways to resolve that maybe possibly the issue .

1. Firstly as `iss` issuer value has v2 endpoint as in provided details
   ,

   ```
   "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/a59..../v2.0",
   ```

   Please go to manifest in the portal and check if
   `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` is also 2 or else change it to 2

   [image]
2. Also as you can see  "aud" is not equal to clientId, but ***audience
   must be equal to clientId*** ...here clientId is given as
   api://MyBackendAppID, but aud claim  from token has
   "MyFrontendAppID".

   So in  appsettings.json remove `api://` prefix of client Id and try
   giving frontendappId.

   ```
   "AzureAd": {
   ...
   "ClientId": "MyFrontendAppID",//modify
   ....
   }
   ```
3. Also please check if exposed scope is present in the code
   configuration also, if not scopes similar to the portal must be
   added in the code.

Comment: thanks for the tips. Only one question what did you mean with point 3. Did you have any example?

Comment: 2nd option must be possible solution case for you according to the error.Regarding 3rd i meants  Scopes in code something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-verification-scope-app-roles?tabs=aspnetcore)

Comment: Changed manifest in both Azure AD Apps to 2. Change appsettings as you mentioned and added the scope (see my update). But I get always a Invalid token error

Comment: Is the scope in code exactly like in the portal i.e. `api://<appId>/access_as_user` (like in the second image you have provided for scopes in portal) . if not try and before executing refresh both portal and app.

Comment: yes tried with both with api:// and without. And refreshed but without solution

Comment: Any other ideas?